# Rails + Passenger + Nignx + Modules

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I try to install Rails + Passenger + Nginx + Modules but I got an error when installer start compiling Nginx:

```
sh ./configure --prefix='/opt/nginx' 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-cc-opt=-Wno-error 
--with-ld-opt=''  
--with-pcre='/tmp/passenger.1x6s546/pcre-8.34' 
--add-module='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-5.0.24/src/nginx_module' 
--with-http_geoip_module 
--with-http_limit_conn_module 
--http_limit_req_module 
--with-http_log_module
```

And after passenger is installed and it start with Nginx it throws an error:

```
 error: ./configure: error: invalid option "--with-http_limit_conn_module"
```

What can be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/trusty/ has some good instructions. Where is ./configure from as are you using different instructions? You're missing the OS that you are using to install this as well.

Comment: I install it through rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module and chose option with adictional modules.

Comment: like this? https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install_as_nginx_module.html